# How do I create a custom filter to arrange selected items at the top of a multi select v-autocomplete in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have this multi select drop down in Vue.js/Vuetify.js that has a custom filter - I know filtering only workswhen you search/type in the field, I was wondering if it's possible to sort by the items that are checked. And put them at the top of the drop down list?

```
<v-autocomplete v-model="defendantCode"
     label="Defendant Code"
     :items="defendantCodeOptions"
     :loading="defendantCodeIsLoading"
     :filter="customFilter"
     clearable
     multiple
     dense>
</v-autocomplete>
```

In my Javascript I'm setting items to be selected like this

```
this.defendantCode = [23,43,556];
```

Now I want to sort the selected to show at the top of the drop down.

Is this possible?

I have a custom filter but understand it's only for searching.

Answer (score 0):

the filter won't work this, because it is executed against the list of items. This gives you no control over changing the order.

I've looked through the source, and I think your best bet is to change the list. here is an example:

```js
  methods: {
    onChange() {
      states = this.states.sort();
      var selected = states.filter(s => this.model.includes(s))
      var notSelected = states.filter(s => !this.model.includes(s))
      this.states = [...selected, ...notSelected];
    }
  },
  mounted(){
    this.onChange(); // for initial sort, you might want to put this somewhere else or add additional listeners
  }
```

```html
<v-autocomplete
  v-model="model"
  :items="states"
  :multiple="true"
  @change="onChange"
>
```

this will re-generate the list every time there is a change. The list gets sorted  first `sort()`, this makes sure that the items are sorted alphabetically always, then it gets split into selected and unselected, and joined together in that order.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data () {
    return {
      model: ['Louisiana', 'Maine', 'Marshall Islands'],
      states: [
        'Alabama', 'Alaska', 'American Samoa', 'Arizona',
        'Arkansas', 'California', 'Colorado', 'Connecticut',
        'Delaware', 'District of Columbia', 'Federated States of Micronesia',
        'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Guam', 'Hawaii', 'Idaho',
        'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky',
        'Louisiana', 'Maine', 'Marshall Islands', 'Maryland',
        'Massachusetts', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota', 'Mississippi',
        'Missouri', 'Montana', 'Nebraska', 'Nevada',
        'New Hampshire', 'New Jersey', 'New Mexico', 'New York',
        'North Carolina', 'North Dakota', 'Northern Mariana Islands', 'Ohio',
        'Oklahoma', 'Oregon', 'Palau', 'Pennsylvania', 'Puerto Rico',
        'Rhode Island', 'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee',
        'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont', 'Virgin Island', 'Virginia',
        'Washington', 'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming',
      ],
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onChange() {
      states = this.states.sort();
      var selected = states.filter(s => this.model.includes(s))
      var notSelected = states.filter(s => !this.model.includes(s))
      this.states = [...selected, ...notSelected];
    }
  },
  mounted(){
    this.onChange()
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://unpkg.com/@mdi/font@3.9.97/css/materialdesignicons.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.0.17/dist/vuetify.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.0.17/dist/vuetify.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-card>
      <v-card-title class="headline font-weight-regular blue-grey white--text">Profile</v-card-title>
      <v-card-text>
        <v-subheader class="pa-0">Where do you live?</v-subheader>
        <v-autocomplete v-model="model" :items="states" :multiple="true" prepend-icon="mdi-city" @change="onChange">
        </v-autocomplete>
      </v-card-text>
    </v-card>
  </v-app>
</div>
```